# In a single terminal window capture the command to start a.out 3 times each running as background job

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, io

On linux terminal window is there a way i can start a program like ./a.out 3 times each running as background jobs. I was told that IO redirection is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ampersand (`&`) after the command to put it in the background. If you want 3 instances of it running in the background, you could do the following:

`./a.out& ./a.out& ./a.out&`

note it doesn't have to immediately follow the command, the following will do the same thing as well:

`./a.out & ./a.out & ./a.out &`

You should then see something like the following (depending on your Linux flavor/shell):

```
[1] 19731
[2] 27320
[3] 12461
```

Where those are the PID's of the separate instances of the programs you started.

Hope that helps.